# How many ways to inject the bean automatically in spring?

Tags: spring

I am new in spring framework and I want to know that how many different ways in spring to inject bean automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can autowire the bean.

1. byType
2. byName and
3. Constructor